# Output Always 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I have a stored procedure and am using a Merge Statement to Insert and Update. This aspect is working as I require.

However, the output when inserting the record is always 1 and I cannot see why? I would be grateful if someone could review this procedure and let me know what I could be doing wrong,.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FileAdd]

@FileId int, 
@FileData varbinary(max), 
@ContentType Varchar(100),
@OperatorId int

AS
BEGIN
--In Memory Table to 
DECLARE @MergeOutput TABLE
(
  Id INT
);

--Merge needs a table to Merge with so using a CTE
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT @FileId as FileId)

--Merge
MERGE INTO [dbo].[Files] as T
USING CTE AS S
ON T.FileId = S.FileId
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (
    FileData,
    ContentType,
    OperatorIdCreated, 
    OperatorIdUpdated
    ) 
    VALUES(
    @FileData,
    @ContentType,
    @OperatorId, 
    @OperatorId
    )
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET 
    FileData = @FileData, 
    ContentType= @ContentType,
    OperatorIdUpdated = @OperatorId, 
    Updated = GetDate()

OUTPUT
INSERTED.FileId
INTO @MergeOutput;

SELECT * FROM @MergeOutput;
END
GO
```

Comment: Are you set on using merge? [There are some things to be aware of](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) and for this, and other reasons, old school UPSERT using `EXISTS` is much easier to manage.

Comment: I prefer using merge, but i dont have to 100% use it as I would rather something work than force something in thats dodgy

Comment: What do you mean the output is 1? It says the inserted `FileId` was `1` but it was actually something different?

Comment: Are you passing 1 into that parameter? What is `FileID` in the destination table? an `Identity` column? Are you truncating this table before you run this code which would make it always 1 if it was an identity field?

Comment: I can only assume your are passing 1 in which would mean you are continually updating the same row and thus outputting the same value each time

Comment: @MartinSmith nit sure what you mean, but the output as I state is always 1, the value from Inserted.FieldId is always returned as 1

Comment: @scsimon nope, the value on a newly inserted record is 0, Im going to try and null that out if it is 0 and see how that goes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting 1 is because that is what is being `UPDATED` or `INSERTED`. When it's the `UPDATED` value, then it is the value are passing into `@FileID`.

[With the `OUTPUT` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> INSERTED Is a column prefix that specifies the value added by the
>   **insert or update** operation.

Thus, what ever value is `UPDATED` (which is `@FileID`) or `INSERTED` (which will be whatever your `FileID` table logic is) this will be returned in your code. If you are always getting 1, then you must me always updating the column for `FileID = 1`.

Changing your bottom to `inserted.*` would show you this, as it would `OUTPUT` the updated row.

[Check the demo here.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c20c895790c8f518c2cb6db6de41b19a)

Comment: The value that is being passed in for the insert is a 0, ive not encountred that before but will null it out and try it

Comment: If you repeatedly pass in the same value it will be returned as it is being updated.

Comment: there is no id of 0 in the table so the merge is never matching on the insert

Comment: If it doesn’t match it inserts though.